# Flex & Bison yyin from Argv[]

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, argv

I'm working on a Flex & Bison project. I got my flex & bison perfectly working but I'm trying to give true argv the input string. So I've changed yyin so that it took the argv[1] but it's actually not working. It just ignores it.

Here is my main.c :

```
#include "parser.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
 extern FILE* yyin;
 yyin = fopen(argv[1],"r");
 yyparse();
}
```

And here is my makefile :

```
all: bison flex main.cpp
   g++ parser.cpp lexer.cpp main.cpp -o parser
   rm lexer.cpp parser.cpp parser.hpp
bison: parser.y
   bison -o parser.cpp parser.y
flex: lexer.l
   flex -o lexer.cpp lexer.l
```

Then I run like this :
`./parser "(2+5)"`

But it does nothing.
Maybe I'm not doing it the right way.

Comment: I think you should take a look at what `fopen` actually does.

Comment: Yeah, i took it from an exemple but seem weird to me that we use fopen. But i can't basically wright 
        `yyin = argv[1];`
Because type doesnt match. 
Sorry if i'm asking dumb question.

Comment: @G.Courmont: You are trying to open a file called **(2+5)** and read from it.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy ok that i understand, but the question is, how can i do it ? Read from argv to change the yyin ?

Comment: @G.Courmont; As far as I know there is no way in standard C to open a string as a file and read from it. Unless someone finds a better way, you could write the contents of `argv[1]` to a file, and then open that file.

Answer (score 1):

Flex provides `yy_scan_string()` which creates a new buffer from a null-terminated string (like `argv[1]`), then switches lexing to use that buffer.

You can use it something like:

```c
int main(int argc, char const * argv[]) {
    YY_BUFFER_STATE buf;

    buf = yy_scan_string(argv[1]);
    yyparse();
    yy_delete_buffer(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

There are other ways to create and manage the buffers, see the *Scanning strings* section of the Flex documentation for more details.